# Problema de conexion a la BD con laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-8

hola compañeros tengo un problema al conectar mi proyecto con la BD,
esta es mi configuracion del env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pruebas
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

cuando hago un migrate

```
php artisan migrate
```

me sale este Error...

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pruebas and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Intente cambiando la el usuario de la base de datos pero nada, tambien limpiando cache con...

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Luego intente probando esa query en mySQL y me salieron estos errores...

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pruebas and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'pruebas' in 'where clause'
```

le puse comillas a las partes que debía ponerlas y si ejecuto la query

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'pruebas' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';

Empty set (0.02 sec)
```

pero no se en que parte puedo cambiar eso en laravel, o hay alguna otra solucion.

por favor.

Comment: puedes agregar la configuración de tu .env. Talvez se deba a una mala configuración.

Comment: puedes verificar si tienes la extensión para la conexión en mysql de php, en windows es `php_pdo_mysql.dll` o si es linux es `pdo_mysql.so`, estos deben estar en el php.ini

Comment: tengo el 'pdo_mysql' sin el '.so' @tecnobyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede, es que no tienes las dependencias instalada de la version de php que usar, dependiendo del sistema que uses es la instalación

Para Windows solo descarga el dll correspondiente de la versión de php que uses, lo puedes descargar de la pagina de [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_MYSQL)

En Linux depende mucho de la distro que uses, si usas debían y derivados, puedes realizarlo con este comando:

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql // dependiendo de la versión que uses de php
```

ya usa vez con la dependencia, vas al archivo `php.ini` y descomentas la linea donde se localiza la librería

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

reinicias tu servidor y debe de detectarte ya el driver.

Comment: tengo estos en el `php.ini`...
`extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite` 
descomente el `pdo_mysql` pero ahora tengo este error...

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator))`

Comment: verifica si este respuesta te funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240102/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-pdo-mysql-so

Comment: no, me sigue saliendo el mismo error, pero muchas gracias

Comment: ya lo pude reparar, gracias