# Erro al hacer una migración en Laravel 7

Tags: php7, laravel-7

Estoy tratando de hacer una migración en Laravel 7, pero lamentablemente me sale el suiente error.
Nota: uso XAMPP

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = almacen and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 671|             throw new QueryException(
672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
673|             );
674|         }
675| 

  +33 vendor frames 
34  artisan:37
  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Comment: ¿Esta habilitada la extenisón PDO en tu php.ini?

Comment: Si esta habilitada, extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema de conexion a la BD con laravel 8](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425843/problema-de-conexion-a-la-bd-con-laravel-8)